# Reproducing photos with vector-based geometric primitives (ellipses, bezier curves)

Tags: gratis, image-processing, image-editor, image-conversion

Anyone knows a free software or a filter/plugin/extension for image processing software that works like [primitive.lol](https://primitive.lol/) does?.

It turns pictures into a [stack of ellipses, rectangles,triangles](https://twitter.com/PrimitivePic/status/1342403945042497537) (= a Cargo Aircraft) or an alignment of [1000s of Beziers Curves](https://twitter.com/PrimitivePic/status/1342365474106040320) (= White Cats).

The software seems only be available on the MacAppStore, and I don't have a Mac.

Image quality and implementation details of the software are less of a concern to me, I am just fascinated by the semi-creative process.
Basically I just want to be able to have access to the vector graphics (not just the final bitmap)

Comment: Mind to include where it should run on? Yes, no Mac – how about an Amiga… errm… BSD? Linux? Windows? If Plugin/Extension: where shall it plug in/extend? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

So, I searched a bit because this filter looks interesting indeed, and it turns out [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) has such a filter built-in. Gimp is free, open-source and available for Windows, Mac and Linux.

It is part of the "G'MIC" filter package and called "Polygonize" in the "Artistic" section. I have tried it on Gimp 2.8.22 on Linux. I cannot guarantee it is available in all versions or on all OS's.

Comment: Thanks for going through all those filters in Gimp (for me, n=548) . I get kind of similar results. However it does not create a an array of raster layers, let alone vector elements. What I meant is was a software that takes the raster graphic and turns it into a vector graphic with1000 cleverly stacked transparent triangles, say. I think CorelDraw has  something like that built-in if I remember correctly (but it's not free). - And with polygonize you can't constain the object type (e.g. "use only triangles")